# Optical vertical justification of table cells

Tags: tables, macros, formatting, automation

I will be very happy if someone could help me format the entries in in the columns 1 to 3 so that they appear in the center of the row as the column 'Tracks' has been centered in the top rule

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]\centering
    \begin{tabular}{lcccc}
        \toprule
        \multirow{2}[3]{*}{Track} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Virtual Station} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Search window} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
        & Lat [\textdegree]& Long [\textdegree] & Lat [\textdegree] & Long [\textdegree]\\
        \midrule
        551 &   42.967165  &  -87.062729  & 43.99  & -87.46  \\
            &              &              & 42.03  & -86.74 \\
         \hline
        7   &   44.370063  &  -86.847797  & 44.87 & -87.01  \\
            &              &              & 43.77 & -86.62 \\
         \hline
        882 &   43.850509  &  -86.949138  & 42.31 & -87.46  \\
            &              &              & 43.85 & -86.94 \\
        \hline
        465 &   45.065718  &  -86.387580  & 45.48 & -86.53  \\
            &              &              & 44.76 & -86.27 \\
        \hline
        338 &   42.471183  &  -86.719330  & 43.08 & -86.49  \\
            &              &              & 41.84 & -86.92 \\
        \hline
        923 &   45.556212  &  -85.851539  & 45.86 & -85.95  \\
            &              &              & 45.20 & -85.73 \\
        \hline
        379 &   45.782886  &  -85.220795  & 45.96 & -85.29  \\
            &              &              & 45.64 & -85.16 \\

        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) it would be nice if you added a full minimal example such that others don't have to guess your preamble. (3) You should also have a look at the `siunitx` package in otder to format units (instead of `\textdegree` and to format numbers in tables (the minuses)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I used `\stackanchors` to build the search window data around the baseline.  I also expressed all latitudes and longitudes in math mode to capture the proper `-` sign.

In `\sa`, the `[2pt]` is the vertical buffer added above and below the `\stackanchor`, while the `[5pt]` is the vertical gap between stacked entries of the search window.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\strutshortanchors{T}
\newcommand\sa[2]{\addstackgap[2pt]{\ensurestackMath{\stackanchor[5pt]{#1}{#2}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]\centering
    \begin{tabular}{lcccc}
        \toprule
        \multirow{2}[3]{*}{Track} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Virtual Station} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Search window} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
        & Lat [\textdegree]& Long [\textdegree] & Lat [\textdegree] & Long [\textdegree]\\
        \midrule
        551 &$   42.967165  $&$  -87.062729  $& \sa{43.99}{42.03}  & \sa{-87.46}{-86.74}\\
         \hline
        7   &$   44.370063  $&$  -86.847797  $& \sa{44.87}{43.77} & \sa{-87.01}{-86.62} \\
         \hline
        882 &$   43.850509  $&$  -86.949138  $& \sa{42.31}{43.85} & \sa{-87.46}{-86.94} \\
        \hline
        465 &$   45.065718  $&$  -86.387580  $& \sa{45.48}{44.76} & \sa{-86.53}{-86.27} \\
        \hline
        338 &$   42.471183  $&$  -86.719330  $& \sa{43.08}{41.84} & \sa{-86.49}{-86.92} \\
        \hline
        923 &$   45.556212  $&$  -85.851539  $& \sa{45.86}{45.20} & \sa{-85.95}{-85.73} \\
        \hline
        379 &$   45.782886  $&$  -85.220795  $& \sa{45.96}{45.64} & \sa{-85.29}{-85.16} \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In principle you need something like

```
\newcommand*\Osborncell[1]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\multirow{2}{*}{#1}\fi
}
```

for the formatting. It simply checks for an empty cell entry: if it is not empty it reformats the current cell to a multirow, hence it is optically justified to the center of the two vertical neighbor cells. The tricky part is to apply this only to the relevant parts of the table. Althoug this could be done by hand like

```
\begin{table}[h]\centering
  \begin{tabular}{lcccc}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}[3]{*}{Track}&
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Virtual Station}&
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Search window}\\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
    & Lat [\textdegree]& Long [\textdegree] & Lat [\textdegree] & Long [\textdegree]\\
    \midrule
    \Osborncell{551} & \Osborncell{42.967165} & \Osborncell{-87.062729}  & 43.99  & -87.46 \\
     & & & 42.03  & -86.74 \\
     ...
```

a little automation could be nice for this kind of table. For this the data input is done prior to the formatting with the following interface change: The tables content is gathered via a macro, here `\tabledata`.

```
 \tabledata{%
    551, 42.967165, -87.062729, 43.99, -87.46;
       ,          ,           , 42.03, -86.74;
  %  \hline
    7  , 44.370063, -86.847797, 44.87, -87.01;
       ,          ,           , 43.77, -86.62;
  %  \hline
    882, 43.850509, -86.949138, 42.31, -87.46;
       ,          ,           , 43.85, -86.94;
  %  \hline
    465, 45.065718, -86.387580, 45.48, -86.53;
       ,          ,           , 44.76, -86.27;
  %  \hline
    338, 42.471183, -86.719330, 43.08, -86.49;
       ,          ,           , 41.84, -86.92;
  %  \hline
    923, 45.556212, -85.851539, 45.86, -85.95;
       ,          ,           , 45.20, -85.73;
  %  \hline
    379, 45.782886, -85.220795, 45.96, -85.29;
       ,          ,           , 45.64, -85.16;
  }
```

Then, the actual table is produced through

```
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
  \toprule
  \multirow{2}[3]{*}{Track}&
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Virtual Station}&
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Search window}\\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
  & Lat [\textdegree] & Long [\textdegree] & Lat [\textdegree] & Long [\textdegree]\\
  \midrule
  \printtabledata
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

(`\printtabledata` prints the tables data specified before.)

[image: showcase]

This is achieved by looping over the data array and storing the information suitably in a token register (`\@toks@table`).

```
\newtoks\@toks@table
\newcounter{currentrow}
\newcounter{currentcolumn}
\def\tabledata#1{\@toks@table{}\@tabledata#1\@end}
\def\@tabledata#1;#2{%
  \stepcounter{currentrow}%
  \mod{\c@currentrow}{2}%
  \ifnum\value{currentrow}=1\else\ifnum\@mod=1
    \@toks@table\expandafter{\the\@toks@table\hline}\fi\fi
  \parserow{#1}%
  \ifx#2\@end\else\expandafter\@tabledata\expandafter#2\fi
}
\def\parserow#1{%
  \setcounter{currentcolumn}{0}%
  \@parserow#1,\@@end
  \@toks@table\expandafter{\the\@toks@table\\}
}
\def\@parserow#1,#2{%
  \stepcounter{currentcolumn}%
  \ifnum\value{currentcolumn}=1\@toks@table\expandafter{\the\@toks@table \Osborncell{#1}}\fi
  \ifnum\value{currentcolumn}=2\@toks@table\expandafter{\the\@toks@table&\Osborncell{#1}}\fi
  \ifnum\value{currentcolumn}=3\@toks@table\expandafter{\the\@toks@table&\Osborncell{#1}}\fi
  \ifnum\value{currentcolumn}>3\@toks@table\expandafter{\the\@toks@table&#1}\fi
  \ifx#2\@@end\else\expandafter\@parserow\expandafter#2\fi
}
```

The counters 'currentrow' and 'currentcolumn' simply keep track of the current position in the data during the loops. The formatting for each column is defined in the definition of `\@parserow`. Here,`\Osborncell` (see above) is applied to the cells of the first three columns.

### Complete Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\makeatletter
\newcount\@mod
\newcommand*{\mod}[2]{%
  \@mod=#1
  \@tempcnta=#2
  \ifnum\@mod<\@tempcnta\else
    \loop
    \advance\@mod by -#2
    \unless\ifnum\@mod<#2
    \repeat
  \fi
}
\newtoks\@toks@table
\newcounter{currentrow}
\newcounter{currentcolumn}
\def\tabledata#1{\@toks@table{}\@tabledata#1\@end}
\def\@tabledata#1;#2{%
  \stepcounter{currentrow}%
  \mod{\c@currentrow}{2}%
  \ifnum\value{currentrow}=1\else\ifnum\@mod=1
    \@toks@table\expandafter{\the\@toks@table\hline}\fi\fi
  \parserow{#1}%
  \ifx#2\@end\else\expandafter\@tabledata\expandafter#2\fi
}
\def\parserow#1{%
  \setcounter{currentcolumn}{0}%
  \@parserow#1,\@@end
  \@toks@table\expandafter{\the\@toks@table\\}
}
\def\@parserow#1,#2{%
  \stepcounter{currentcolumn}%
  \ifnum\value{currentcolumn}=1\@toks@table\expandafter{\the\@toks@table \Osborncell{#1}}\fi
  \ifnum\value{currentcolumn}=2\@toks@table\expandafter{\the\@toks@table&\Osborncell{#1}}\fi
  \ifnum\value{currentcolumn}=3\@toks@table\expandafter{\the\@toks@table&\Osborncell{#1}}\fi
  \ifnum\value{currentcolumn}>3\@toks@table\expandafter{\the\@toks@table&#1}\fi
  \ifx#2\@@end\else\expandafter\@parserow\expandafter#2\fi
}
\def\printtabledata{\the\@toks@table}
\newcommand*\Osborncell[1]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\multirow{2}{*}{#1}\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]\centering
  \tabledata{%
    551, 42.967165, -87.062729, 43.99, -87.46;
       ,          ,           , 42.03, -86.74;
    7  , 44.370063, -86.847797, 44.87, -87.01;
       ,          ,           , 43.77, -86.62;
    882, 43.850509, -86.949138, 42.31, -87.46;
       ,          ,           , 43.85, -86.94;
    465, 45.065718, -86.387580, 45.48, -86.53;
       ,          ,           , 44.76, -86.27;
    338, 42.471183, -86.719330, 43.08, -86.49;
       ,          ,           , 41.84, -86.92;
    923, 45.556212, -85.851539, 45.86, -85.95;
       ,          ,           , 45.20, -85.73;
    379, 45.782886, -85.220795, 45.96, -85.29;
       ,          ,           , 45.64, -85.16;
  }
  \begin{tabular}{lcccc}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}[3]{*}{Track}&
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Virtual Station}&
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Search window}\\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
    & Lat [\textdegree] & Long [\textdegree] & Lat [\textdegree] & Long [\textdegree]\\
    \midrule
    \printtabledata
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

### Remark

As a small side note and as for the comment by @egreg you might want to try using `siunitx` to format the numbers in your table. Besides loading the package you need two little tweaks:

1. The `\Osborncell` macro:

   ```
   \newcommand*\Osborncell[1]{%
     \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\multirow{2}{*}{\num{#1}}\fi
   }
   ```
2. The `\@parserow` macro:

   ```
   \def\@parserow#1,#2{%
     ...
     \ifnum\value{currentcolumn}>3
       \@toks@table\expandafter{\the\@toks@table&\num{#1}}\fi
     \ifx#2\@@end\else\expandafter\@parserow\expandafter#2\fi
   }
   ```

[image: remark_example]

Comment: Nice, but the hyphens should be minus signs; `siunitx` would surely help.

Comment: Thanks @egreg! Do you mean `\num{-87.46}` etc.?

Comment: In this case it might do, because the number of decimal digits is fixed in each column.

Comment: @egreg - Nice, I will add a remark.